# How to ignore parents padding with true 100% width?

Tags: css

I have an special page (inner element) which shall ignore the outer padding but it have to be 100% wide. Around each page is a *container* with a padding of 10px.

So a negative margin will result in something below 100% since some percent are hidden overflow.

```
margin-left: -10px /* 10px is the padding of the outer element */
```

**Is there a way to ignore the outer padding without *moving* the inner element?**
Well removing the padding on the outer would be possible but actually way to much effort for this.

Comment: Have you tried box-sizing: border-box?

Answer (score 2):

Ah I could solve it myself. Probably not the best solution but it works for me. Thats fine.

```
.inner {
    width: calc(100% + 10px);
    margin-left: -10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question correctly, you could just use a combination of negative `margin` + `padding` to achieve that.

```css
.outer {
    padding: 10px;
    background: pink; /*you should not see this*/
}
.inner {
    margin: -10px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">hello world!</div>
</div>
```